# istio operator: pass ingress mTLS certs via files

Tags: istio, mtls

I am trying to pass mTLS certs to istio ingress gateway via files and not via secrets.
Vault init-container will store certs at

```
/etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
/etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.cert
/etc/istio/ingressgateway-ca-certs/ca-chain.cert.pem
```

So I m trying to remove secret element via patch like this

```
      - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-ca-certs].emptyDir
        value: {}
      - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-certs].emptyDir
        value: {}
      - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-certs].secret
      - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-certs].secret.secretName
      - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-ca-certs].secret.secretName
      - path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-ca-certs].secret
```

but it is not working.
Doc says, "For delete, value should be unset."

```
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#K8sObjectOverlay-PathValue
```

istioctl manifest generate command still includes secret section.
I also tried setting the value to "unset" but (as exptected) ended up using unset as literal value for secret name.
Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used this to delete it since vault sidecar will mount it.

```
- path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-ca-certs]         
- path: spec.template.spec.volumes[name:ingressgateway-certs]
```

but in final solution, configured and rendered certificates at a different path to avoid conflicts with default paths. E.g.

```
/etc/istio/ingressgateway/certs/tls.key
/etc/istio/ingressgateway/certs/tls.cert
/etc/istio/ingressgateway/ca-certs/ca-chain.cert.pem
```